# How to Add Column from MS Excel to MS Project - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I am writing a macro to add a column of data from an MS Excel sheet into an already existing MS Project document. When I run my macro the correct project is opened, but I get an error message saying that the project I opened has been deleted, even though it has not been deleted.

Here is my current macro:

```
Sub newProjectColumn()
Dim appProj As MSProject.Application
Dim aProg As MSProject.Project
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'~~> Open MS Project
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set appProj = CreateObject("Msproject.Application")

appProj.FileOpen "Project_1.mpp"

Set aProg = appProj.ActiveProject

appProj.Visible = True

'~~> Next, create new Column in project
TableEditEx Name:="Project_1.mpp", TaskTable:=True, _
    NewFieldName:="Actual Duration", Title:="Actual Duration", Width:=12, _
    ShowInMenu:=True, _
    ColumnPosition:=29

'~~> Next, copy T:T from Excel.Then, paste to 29th column (i,29) in Project.
Set Rng = ws.Range("T:T")
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Rng
SelectTaskColumn Column:="Actual Duration"

End Sub
```

Any help on what I have done wrong or if there is a better approach would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Which line does the error occur? What is the **excact** error message? And did you try giving the full path for `appProj.FileOpen` like `"C:\What\Ever\Your\Path\Is\Project_1.mpp"`? And make sure you prefix  everything that should happen in your Project with `aProg.` (eg. `aProg.TableEditEx …` or Excel assumes to do it in the ActiveSheet of Excel not in Project (check also the copy/paste, etc).

Comment: please always [edit] your question so the code can be formatted. Code in comments is mostly unreadable.

Comment: Sorry having formatting issues with the code, but...
The exact error message is : "Run-time error '1004': The view or report cannot be displayed because the table 'Project_1.mpp' on which it is based has been deleted." I added the aProg before it and got a new error message: "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: both erros occur on the table edit lines

Comment: My bad but `TableEditEx` should be `appProj.TableEditEx` due to [Application.TableEditEx Method (Project)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865438.aspx).

Comment: okay, after adding appProj to the beginning I still get the first error (run-time '1004') but not the other error

Comment: The Name argument of the `TableEditEx` method is the name of the table, not the name of the project. [MSDN TableEditEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Project-VBA/articles/application-tableeditex-method-project)

Comment: Thank you I have corrected this but still get an error "This is not a valid number for the ColumnPosition argument" but columns 1-28 are filled and 29 would be the first available column to add a column. Does that portion of code not add a row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code you need to update the Actual Duration column. Change the table name as necessary. Update the range reference as necessary; do not include a header cell.

```
  ' add Actual Duration as the first column & apply the table changes
  appProj.TableEditEx Name:="Entry", TaskTable:=True, _
    NewFieldName:="Actual Duration", Title:="Actual Duration", Width:=12, ColumnPosition:=0
  appProj.TableApply "Entry"

  ' copy updated values from Excel (no headers) and paste in new column in Project
  Range("T2:T100").Copy
  appProj.SelectColumn 2
  appProj.EditPaste

  ' delete the column
  appProj.ColumnDelete
```

Note that when adding a column using the `TableEditEx` method, the indexes start at 0 whereas when selecting a column using the `SelectColumn` method, the indexes start at 2.

[TableEditEx method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Project-VBA/articles/application-tableeditex-method-project)

[SelectColumn method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/project-vba/articles/application-selectcolumn-method-project)