# MS-PROJECT how do I apply Application.AddNewColumn method correctly?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I would like to make a column (Summary) visible with my code at the beginning  to retrieve from this data and close it again at the end of the code.
In my code.
So far in my code, the column summary must always be displayed for it to work, but I do not want to.
That's why I want to show the column at the beginning and hide it at the end

```vb
Sub BalkenFormatieren()

    Dim Inhalt, Trennzeichen As String
    Dim i, Werte As Integer
    Dim ArrDaten(0 To 248, 0 To 248) As Double
    Dim OriginalTaskID As Long
    Dim Tsk As Task
    Dim LastTaskRow As Long


    LastTaskRow = ActiveProject.Tasks.Count
    Trennzeichen = "_"



    'Von - Bis Spalten
    For i = 0 To LastTaskRow - 1

        'definiere Zeile mit schleife
        SelectTaskField Row:=i + 1, Column:="Summary", RowRelative:=False
        Inhalt = ActiveCell

        'Wenn Zelle = Ja dann Fromatieren
        If Inhalt = "Yes" Then
            GanttBarFormatEx MiddleShape:=5, righttext:="text29"
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Which data do you want to add in your summary column ?

Comment: Hi Dorian 
Sorry, I did not explain it well, my English is not great.
I will only query the data from the summary, this is why I want to make it visible.  My goal is to format all collecting processes with my code. This works too, unfortunately only if the column summary is also visible.

Comment: So you  just want to add an other column called "Summary" ? When do you want to Hide your column summary ? This is unclear. Kindest regards

Comment: I wonna hide the Collumn Summary at the end of my code.

Comment: I found the commands addnewcollumn and columninsert, but I do not understand how to use them.

Comment: I know there are only basics but unfortunately I not find enough information about VBA with ms project, so I would be very grateful if you could help me

Comment: sure I will, To resume what you asked for : Create a new column called summary + Hide it at the end of your code ?

Comment: yes, although the column in ms project already exists, it is just hidden. So I want to insert them and not create new and hide at the end again. many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add or delete a column to a Gantt Chart table, use the [TableEditEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Project.Application.TableEditEx) method as shown in this SO post: [How to add a new column in Microsoft Project...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999039/how-to-add-a-new-column-in-microsoft-project-from-excel-vba) and [How to Add Column...to MS Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634705/how-to-add-column-from-ms-excel-to-ms-project-vba).

---

### But there is a better way to get a task's properties.

You don't need to add columns in order to get the active task's properties. Use the [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.cell.task) property of the [ActiveCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.activecell).

```
For i = 0 To LastTaskRow - 1

    SelectRow Row:=i + 1, RowRelative:=False

    If ActiveCell.Task.Summary Then
        GanttBarFormatEx MiddleShape:=5, righttext:="text29"
    End If

Next i
```

Note that this uses the [SelectRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.selectrow) method which has an argument called `RowRelative`. When looping through all tasks like this, it's best to set that argument to `False` and set the `Row` argument to the absolute position that you want; otherwise `RowRelative` defaults to `True` and the selection position moves forward *from the current selection*, not the first task.

Comment: Hi Rachel
Thank you for your help. :)
i tried it, when i use the code exactli like that the error code: 
"Compile error: Argument not optional" comes. so i have to use "SelectTaskField Row:=i + 1, Column:="Summary", RowRelative:=False" but then its not work without the visible column. How i can make it?

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that. I fixed the code. Be sure to use `SelectRow` rather than `SelectTaskField` and use the `RowRelative:=False` argument, otherwise it defaults to true and moves the selection point from the current selection rather than from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you Rachel
The perfect solution. :)
Can you possibly give me a hint where I can find training material on the topic vba-Project?
for me it is very difficult to get in to the theme

Comment: The Microsoft documentation is not very deep, but it does cover the entire api: Start by learning about the [Task object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task), [Tasks collection object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.tasks(object)), and [Application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application). Use Google and Stack Overflow to find additional information.